# CAS w/ SPNEGO Authentication error

Tags: authentication, kerberos, cas, spnego

I'm trying to set up CAS SSO with SPNEGO on a Windows environment. I've followed all the instructions in http://jasig.github.io/cas/4.0.x/installation/SPNEGO-Authentication.html but the authentication process fails.

This is the output from the cas.log:

```
2015-03-04 11:36:22,732 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.support.spnego.web.flow.SpnegoNegociateCredentialsAction] - Authorization header not found. Sending WWW-Authenticate header
2015-03-04 11:36:22,738 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.web.support.CasArgumentExtractor] - Extractor did not generate service.
2015-03-04 11:36:22,738 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.support.spnego.web.flow.SpnegoCredentialsAction] - SPNEGO Authorization header found with 1800 bytes
2015-03-04 11:36:22,739 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.support.spnego.web.flow.SpnegoCredentialsAction] - Obtained token: `‚A+ ‚50‚1 $0"   *†H‚÷  *†H†÷
+‚7
¢‚‚`‚ÿ   *†H†÷ n‚î0‚ê ¡¢     £‚a‚0‚ ¡    STU.EDU¢$0" ¡0HTTPrenato-pc.stu.edu£‚Ò0‚Î ¡¢‚À‚¼';Kù«î  Qx‹¦ô¨Oö©$É(L)AµyaC²}wÚ(W+ˆeŽ»vj[èAe¿…íZÍ®CŸ”ÑúD€‘É’5©–k¼/ÎŸêý7¨ÊÙþÅ’B´;Ñ€ãâ½¿ÌWat,ó5LJýÅÙ{¡3ê”G¦GÄ¥IyÇ¤é¯Õ?9k`Zz!;cºE­•Û[·˜Œª|{´:t%j¡ía”??H£³òØ×ë÷œoG ¦]+é<ÌàÊ¨®2›Uòx|ã¨±: a%ÆÔaJ6_½B:"õ¯FÜª"\N+¼ª
çšòÓ%Öá?xõyƒ;à¿ºõ$ÀŒã=»@›¹õç4 ²m>„¥U,»G!Ô½‰ô—C÷È‡Ý½o"ß;=ÿ™fáÉÁ¸^ŽÒÛÇÔa~µ‚üë‡³× ]Kôp2jž¬ÔP^§2§€jöù)4LLª˜“Œ‘¸"S8‚½óÞ°ÊæÏ‘R<%2Iÿ{‚E§½6¨FÌkÙ„<¡ãyŽù g]ü.B&²Äõ-ò\¿%:ØydˆTÈÊ jù® Æ®XŠ0EC§×CôèG?]b Ž#6“¾(3z`ñ×ðCWµkm¦<9µÓ^4éÐ5«›éÿÄ»«_™1åÁÖZÉ}ÁªG€0±½H¿Ì%oÎW‡Hj{¨8ÕÉ÷>Í8?×Ù­ZW)’¤žtK2é^A$(k¦ÒÇFñÞ¤Ç°¬@ÒÑÕHYXëªöÏ³gšÙK!9r(a9«ÐÜçPÓ¯ù[ºò«w¹Åm_#ÐÐyÚnVêø?ª3­”›‚ Š§‰¦É”˜3iÅ_ûÄ¦¬8€ËókOŠ2uSkÒ[àù†hG³õí:aÌIUg´‹§ñÍSŸr2a?¥C“Ãpv2ÃÚ"Fk•W%\$Žò³ÇÁ8B@ðŠj‡xŒx ÈÛtSE½QMÓ¡x™I?•æW§‘¶¿èà?
†ÏÅÎœßù›Ôžå?Ÿ‘˜‚e¾B¿L?$$8Ú`¼@p©‰ú0}´ðŒÎ`hâÄ¤?    M   ¶>[UMC*Ö#ã½Xùd…!#$?
=²^cÌZ…&þ³P#q[©ƒB^t?PjÁWd~…©?¥ZƒêQ!)h:=“öy(‹?©½ä‡£ú]´1ìEØxÆ7‹BÞôÒ‹Ámr}kß½Ø&Ãxšö+ h((Ÿçå|?¼ÈNZô{hÎŽŒ_ª?}žl?_¼áa¤?¼0?¹ ¢?±?®ú4“kuñO§Bq9¸A¦0cÂ©?0ƒòÕ‚N¶~)¨$TyÚì%µÈÓÉÌ\üšzÇ˜Å™?$QSªØºrÝž :Ä®6¤2ì¦Ä74Œù‰pÆäL?÷z¸çz’­ì3Ó$ß¢Ý¨?þNVo™qí—§ˆ´u¨Þ“Âè?É×&‘cÎ¢Y& «JèÈYU£§(¯…Ô°'/~ðÁó±ò“™F²”Ä8"ú
```

This is the output from the tomcat server:

```
04-Mar-2015 11:34:00.187 SEVERE [http-nio-8443-exec-6] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [cas] in context with path [/cas] threw exception [Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError] with root cause
 java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Byte;
    at org.jasig.cas.support.spnego.util.SpnegoConstants.<clinit>(SpnegoConstants.java:52)
    at org.jasig.cas.support.spnego.authentication.principal.SpnegoCredential.isTokenNtlm(SpnegoCredential.java:133)
    at org.jasig.cas.support.spnego.authentication.principal.SpnegoCredential.<init>(SpnegoCredential.java:79)
    at org.jasig.cas.support.spnego.web.flow.SpnegoCredentialsAction.constructCredentialsFromRequest(SpnegoCredentialsAction.java:79)
    at org.jasig.cas.web.flow.AbstractNonInteractiveCredentialsAction.doExecute(AbstractNonInteractiveCredentialsAction.java:73)
    at org.springframework.webflow.action.AbstractAction.execute(AbstractAction.java:188)
    at org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutor.execute(ActionExecutor.java:51)

04-Mar-2015 10:41:58.240 SEVERE [http-nio-8443-exec-5] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [cas] in context with path [/cas] threw exception [Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.jasig.cas.support.spnego.util.SpnegoConstants] with root cause
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.jasig.cas.support.spnego.util.SpnegoConstants
    at org.jasig.cas.support.spnego.authentication.principal.SpnegoCredential.isTokenNtlm(SpnegoCredential.java:133)
    at org.jasig.cas.support.spnego.authentication.principal.SpnegoCredential.<init>(SpnegoCredential.java:79)
    at org.jasig.cas.support.spnego.web.flow.SpnegoCredentialsAction.constructCredentialsFromRequest(SpnegoCredentialsAction.java:79)
    at org.jasig.cas.web.flow.AbstractNonInteractiveCredentialsAction.doExecute(AbstractNonInteractiveCredentialsAction.java:73)
    at org.springframework.webflow.action.AbstractAction.execute(AbstractAction.java:188)
```

I'm guessing that SPNEGO authentication is failing at [Step 5](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995329.http-sso-1-fig03(l=en-us).gif) (Negotiate w/ SPNEGO Token). Does anyone know how to troubleshoot this? Thanks!